# Convert http post and save to XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to write a program that takes in http post data from a contact form and then process the form to put into .xml format.  I can create some of the tags that is required but no values are inputted when the form is sent.  Here is the example form code:

```
<form action="t.php" target="_top" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div   style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div>       
<div class="form-field title">
<div class="input select"><label for="title">Title</label>
<select id="title">
    <option value="">(Please choose)</option>
    <option value="0">Mr</option>
    <option value="1">Mrs</option>
    <option value="2">Miss</option>
</select></div>     </div>
<div class="form-field float-left">
    <div class="input text"><label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input name="fname" value="" maxlength="150" type="text" id="fname"/></div>         
</div>
    <div class="form-field float-left ">
        <div class="input text"><label for="lname">Last Name</label>
        <input name="lname" value="" maxlength="150" type="text" id="lname"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
```

Here is the php file to do processing:

```
<?php
$xmldoc = new DomDocument( '1.0' );  
$xmldoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xmldoc->formatOutput = true;
$title = $_POST['title'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

if( $xml = file_get_contents( 'data.xml') ) {
    $xmldoc->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );

// find the headercontent tag
$root = $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('headercontent')->item(0);

// create the <lead> tag
$lead = $xmldoc->createElement('lead');
$numAttribute = $xmldoc->createAttribute("num");
$numAttribute->value = $productNum;
$lead->appendChild($numAttribute);

// add the lead tag before the first element in the <headercontent> tag
    $root->insertBefore( $lead, $root->firstChild );

 $titleElement = $xmldoc->createElement('title');
 $lead->appendChild($titleElement);
 $titleText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($title);
 $titleElement->appendChild($titleText);

$fnameElement = $xmldoc->createElement('fname');
$lead->appendChild($fnameElement);
$fnameText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($fname);
$fnameElement->appendChild($fnameText);

$lnameElement = $xmldoc->createElement('lname');
$lead->appendChild($lnameElement);
$lnameText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($lname);
$lnameElement->appendChild($lnameText);


$xmldoc->save('data.xml');
echo "data saved.";
?>
```

But this is the output I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<headercontent>
  <lead>
       <title></title>
       <fname></fname>
       <lname></lname>
  </lead>
</headercontent>
```

It is just appending the  container tag (which is desired), but is not putting in the values (not desired).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I don't see any `<form>` element wrapping your input fields?

Comment: Apologies, ammended the code above for the <form> tags

Comment: Well your select has no name attribute (although you seem to be attempting to populate the `$title` variable via a url parameter?). Just to check, is this the entire xml you are trying to create?

Comment: Have you tried simply doing: `$xmldoc->createElement( "title", $title );` and so on? Or perhaps you could try `$lead->appendChild($titleElement);` after you have appended the actual text node? Also, make sure so `$title`, `$fname` and `$lname` really contains the appropriate data.

Comment: Try to enable error reporting in `t.php`. You also have an undefined variable called `$productNum` in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the info, its inputting the values correctly, I had to add the 'select name' attribute and the 'input name' to the 3 tags - will post back the correct code.

Comment: Be careful with the second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` it might break if the text contains an `&`. Creating the text node separately avoids that.